# add numbers from Different dicts in for loop

Tags: python

i have here this dict :

```py
dict = {
    "A": {
        "value": 5
    },
    "B": {
        "value": -3
    },
    "C": {
        "value": -2
    },
    "D":{
        "value": 2
    },
    "E":{
        "value": -2
    }

}
```

i want To collect all the values
and sum it up when it equals 0

to be something like this:

```py
newDict = {
    "0": {
        # A + B + C = 0 , so combine it togather
        # 5 + -3 + -2 = 0
        "A":{
            "value": 5
        },
        "B": {
            "value": -3
        },
        "C": {
            "value": -2
        },
    },
    # when its = 0 start new dict
    "1":{
         # D + E = 0 , so combine it togather
         # 2 + -2 = 0
         "D":{
            "value": 2
        },
        "E":{
            "value": -2
        }
    },
    # etc....
```

i hope its a clear question
this is my first time on stackover flow
thank u all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple idea is to first use a list to store the split dictionary, and then use the dictionary comprehension to build the result after splitting:

```
>>> mp
{'A': {'value': 5},
 'B': {'value': -3},
 'C': {'value': -2},
 'D': {'value': 2},
 'E': {'value': -2}}
>>> mp_lst = []
>>> val_sum = 0
>>> for k, v in mp.items():
...     if not val_sum:
...         mp_lst.append({})
...     val_sum += v['value']
...     mp_lst[-1][k] = v
...
>>> {str(i): elem for i, elem in enumerate(mp_lst)}
{'0': {'A': {'value': 5}, 'B': {'value': -3}, 'C': {'value': -2}},
 '1': {'D': {'value': 2}, 'E': {'value': -2}}}
```